# SQL Syntax error when trying to draw data from database despite it working before

Tags: python, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7EhP.png)pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select `date` as date,`time` as time,`crane_n` as crane_Name,`db57_dbw700` as db57_dbw700,`db57_dbw702` as db57_dbw702,`db57_dbw704` as db57_dbw704,`db57_dbw706` as db57_dbw706,`db57_dbw708` as db57_dbw708 from edp_raw.armg_subset where crane_n in ('PRM7101' , 'PRM7102') and edp_load_dt >= '20220801' and edp_load_dt <= '20220802'': ('42000', "[42000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:17 cannot recognize input near 'as' 'date' ',' in selection target (80) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Not too sure what is the issue, my coding line worked before but suddenly its broken

```
address = "`date` as Date,`time` as Time,`crane_n` as Crane_Name," + ",".join("`{0}` as {0}".format(x) for x in variables)
    
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=PROD-Knoxx HIVE 64 Bit;TDS_Version = 7.2;UID="+uID+";PWD=" + password + ";",autocommit=True)
    df_data = pd.read_sql_query("select "+address+" from edp_raw.armg_subset where crane_n in ('PRM7101' , 'PRM7102') and edp_load_dt >= '"+batch_dt_start+"' and edp_load_dt <= '"+batch_dt_end+"'", 
                             cnxn)
    cnxn.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzJ3y.png)

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your problem? You can add screenshots,  example datasets where this occurs, helpful thing like that so we can try and help you!

Comment: if it is working earlier and suddenly broken could be a configuration or deriver error. did you check these ?

Comment: i have inserted two image links on where the error occurs and what it looks like, thanks!